# How to scrape 2nd sheet in public google sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this link to a public google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HplWfW1T_XPF45wondzxsTOd5M2VijT-LaDJ9hVOH7Y/edit

Which takes me to a google sheet with 2 sheets in it, Sheet1 and Sheet2. I want to scrape sheet2.

But even when I add the parameter gid=367705858 (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HplWfW1T_XPF45wondzxsTOd5M2VijT-LaDJ9hVOH7Y/edit#gid=367705858) it still scrapes Sheet1.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HplWfW1T_XPF45wondzxsTOd5M2VijT-LaDJ9hVOH7Y/edit#gid=367705858")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
  print([i.text for i in row.find_all("td")])
```

Comment: Maybe it could be better to handle this with the Sheets API rather than BS

Comment: Is it possible to use the Sheets API on a public google sheet that I don't own?

Comment: Yep, you need to authenticate anyway because the APIs require it but this is more a requirement of the API and not at all about the Google Sheet doc since it is public.

Answer (score 1):

When you have already known the sheet names and the Spreadsheet is publicly shared, for example, how about changing the endpoint? When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following script? This endpoint is used with [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

#### Sample script:

In this modified script, the values can be retrieved from the specific sheet using the sheet name.

```js
import csv
import requests

r = requests.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HplWfW1T_XPF45wondzxsTOd5M2VijT-LaDJ9hVOH7Y/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=Sheet2")
values = [row for row in csv.reader(r.text)]
print(values)
```

- When this script is run, `[['i want to scrape this']]` is returned.
- If you want to use the sheet ID, please modify the endpoint as follows. When the following endpoint is used, the same result is also obtained.

  ```
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HplWfW1T_XPF45wondzxsTOd5M2VijT-LaDJ9hVOH7Y/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=367705858
  ```

#### Note:

- If you want to use Sheets API to the publicly shared Spreadsheet, you can retrieve the values from the publicly shared Spreadsheet using an API key. But, if you want to update the Spreadsheet, it is required to use the access token retrieved from OAuth2 or the service account. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)